# Structured Schema.org data is getting corrupted by Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, structured-data

I added FAQ Schema on my Wordpress website. But somehow the code is getting corrupted when testing it using [the schema.org testing tools](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data). Weird thing is that it is showing in the page source code (checking in browser) correctly.

Example of FAQ schema.org code:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "Will plain text show correctly?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Yea, plain text is showing up fine."
    }
  },{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "Why does this code not show correctly?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "But when adding <a href=https://google.com> links </a> or for example <strong>bold</strong> text there seems to be problems. Closing tags seems to dissappear somehow."
    }
  }]
}
</script>
```

[Image: When testing the code in validator it is showing just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CanjB.png)

[Image: Then I post the code on my Wordpress website. Classic editor. It shows fine when I check the page source code in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0cJD.png)

But then when I run the page URL in validator...

[Image: I get this messed up code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ2YC.png)

[Image: Which results in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U40qP.png)

I'm struggeling with this issue for a while now, can't find anything about it. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Tom: Classic editor edits content - HTML `<body>`.Your schema code belongs in HTML `<head>` section. You must learn HTML and [WordPress theme basics](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) to make this work.

Comment: Alternate: Customizer for your theme might have a section for `Add Script`. Paste schema in that area.

Comment: The data can be placed anywhere. From Google's documentation:

"The data, enclosed within the <script type="application/ld+json"> ... </script> tags as shown in the examples below, may be placed in either the <HEAD> or <BODY> region of the page that displays that event."

Comment: I added your script to `<body>` with WP editor - it worked. Try adding single quotes to your link `href='https://google.com'`